# Smoothly transform a square into text in svg/javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there any way to have an svg square and transform it with a transitional animation into a text (which I assume it is vectorial)?

If yes, is there any example or library available I can use in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good library for that would be [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/). There is even an [example](http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html) showing that functionality.